# background-size transition on hover causes chrome to "shake" background image

Tags: css, background-image, transition, background-size

I am trying to achieve an effect I saw recently, where background image zooms on hover. I pretty much did it with example here: https://jsfiddle.net/qyh6nbwt/ but it seems to be very shaky (you will understand what I mean by hovering over it), I'm on osx running latest chrome version, have not checked it in other browsers yet.
Is there a way to make it smoother, so it doesn't "shake" on zoom in?

HTML

```
<div id="example">
    test
</div>
```

CSS

```
#example {
   background-image: url(http://www.jeroenkemperman.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Johns_Inc_Pizza_Spaghetti_wikipediacommons.jpg);

    background-position: center center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    transition:all 1000ms ease;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#example:hover {
    background-size: 160% auto;
}
```

Comment: You can sort of fix it with adding `transform: scale(1.1);` onto the `:hover`, but this doesn't fix it completely. Very interested to see why this is.

Comment: does it have to be a background image?

Comment: Well, i have dirty workaround if you want to see : https://jsfiddle.net/qyh6nbwt/2/ 
But its seems chrome performance issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use transform, scale.

so just instead of setting the bg image to 160% use

```
transform:scale(1.5);
```

some information about the transform css property you can find [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

to use the transform scale in your case you will need a wrapper with overflow hidden so just the inner div gets bigger and cut of by the outer div.

see updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/qyh6nbwt/1/)

greetings timmi

Comment: This is a simple solution, but this also zooms in on the text "Test" which might have gone against OP's intentions.

Comment: I was having problems when a transition on the background-size of a div with a large background-image (2Mb) made the browser image cache to crash, forcing me to "force refresh" (CTRL+F5) to recover the image in all the browser tabs this image appears. Changing the background-size transition to a transform:scale, bypassed this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Used transform scale instead of a background-size change transition: https://jsfiddle.net/qyh6nbwt/

```
transform: scale(2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I made this my mission to figure this out, turns out it wasn't quite as simple of a fix as I thought.

It's a little dirty, but you need to frame your `div` within a `div` like this:

```
<div class="example">
    <div></div>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Then from here, you can target the zooms more accurately, like this:

```
div.example {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div.example > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background-image: url('http://www.jeroenkemperman.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Johns_Inc_Pizza_Spaghetti_wikipediacommons.jpg');
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.example:hover > div {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    transform: scale(2,2);    
}
```

You can adjust the zoom and speed using the `scale` and `transition` properties.

Here is a working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/286/)** to demonstrate. Hope this helps, I checked in Chrome/Safari/Firefox and it seems to work pretty well.