# Transition on css background-size property doesn't work as expected on Chrome

Tags: css, transition, background-size

I already searched for this and did some test and only found half of the answer.

Actually the transition property doesn't work as it should (on Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m) on a background-size when only one value is set, in my case :

Doesn't work:

```
.el {
  background-size: 1200px;
  transition: background-size .5s linear;
}

.el:hover {
  background-size: 1000px;
}
```

Works :

```
.el {
  background-size: 1200px 1000px;
  transition: background-size .5s linear;
}

.el:hover {
  background-size: 1000px 1000px;
}
```

The problems is that if I set a second value my background image is distorted (which is logic). The second value can't be auto (it doesn't work).

Is there anyone who finally found the solution?

Please avoid :
  - You forget prefixing, I obviously tested it with all possible prefix.

Here is the example (it works as expected on mozilla Firefox) :
http://codepen.io/romaingranai/pen/PzJrdm

Thank you

Comment: Probably related: [background-size transition on hover causes chrome to “shake” background image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30218476)

Comment: Can you use percentages? Like this : `.el:hover {background-size: 90% 90%;}` ? It should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not shaky at all, it simply doesn't work. It would be probably shaky if it was working but it's another problem. ;)

Comment: @PascalGoldbach I tried the percent (and it works, not because of percent but because I set 2 values) but my background-image is distorted when using 2 values (which is logic).

Comment: I mean you can't use percents on both `background-size`? (on `.el` and `el:hover`, with the same value on x and y, in that case your background is not stretched)

Comment: @PascalGoldbach Not sure if I understand properly, but if I set, let say background-size: 90% 90%; the background-image will be stretch because the height of the image will be 90% of the container height and the width will be 90% percent of the container width. the percentages are related to the container dimensions not to the image itself.

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: @PascalGoldbach, no worries, It's a bug apparently (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072)